# Why is my useFetch function called twice?

Tags: react-hooks

I'm trying to build my first function using React Hooks that fetches data from an API Endpoint. The code is shown below.

In my React component:

```js
const [{ data, isLoading, isError }] = useFetch(
  'https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=apple'
);
console.log(data);
```

In a file called `requests.js` that I import:

```js
export const useFetch = (url) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsError(false);
      setIsLoading(true);
      try {
        const result = await axios(url);
        setData(result.data);
      } catch (error) {
        setIsError(true);
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [url]);
  return [{ data, isLoading, isError }];
};
```

While it works, whenever I refresh the browser, the call to the endpoint is made twice. Why is this and how can I make it only be called once?

Comment: Sounds more like your component may be getting remounted? Code looks fine and `url` not changing would prevent a double API call.

Comment: Looks like url is changing when you are using the hook. Try to remove it from the dependencies of `useEffects`.

Comment: Would suggest to use [**useMemo**](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) to optimise your re-renders

Comment: @Alvaro, example scenario on why it might happen in his case?

Comment: @AlexanderKim I think the 3 possiblities are: 1.the component is being used more than once. 2.The component is being mounted & unmounted & mounted again. 3.The url parameter is being changed, for example, inside the component using the hook: `const [url, setUrl] = useState("https://example.com/1"); useFetch(url); useEffect(() => {setUrl("https://example.com/2");}, []);` or in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the dependencies from your `useEffect()` should resolve the problem:

```js
const [{ data, isLoading, isError }] = useFetch(
  'https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=apple'
);
console.log(data);
```

```js
export const useFetch = (url) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsError(false);
      setIsLoading(true);
      try {
        const result = await axios(url);
        setData(result.data);
      } catch (error) {
        setIsError(true);
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []/* Will run once */);
  return [{ data, isLoading, isError }];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone has the same issue but the response from @miroslav-glamuzina don't work, maybe this would:

I was passing a nested object `video` in the fetch body.
When mutating one field of this object, the query would be performed again.

It turns out that the [`watch` parameter of `useFetch`](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch#params) is set to `true` by default.

```js
const { error } = await useFetch('/api/schedule', {
  method: 'PUT',
  body: { video },
  watch: false
})
```

Setting `watch` to `false`, did fix the issue for me.